# Different validation contexts in ASP.Net and how to handle this

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, validation, .net-6.0

I have two endpoints in my ASP.net backend.  One that takes an object with optional null parameters i.e. not required and also without any range checking so that this object can be stored in the database and a second that takes an ID of an object in the database.  In this second endpoint I want to get the object out of the database and perform further validation.  I.e. the user needs to have set all the optional values to be valid in range values for this second endpoint to work.

Basically I have two different endpoints that have the same data object but different validation needs.

eg

```
public class AnObject 
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public double? Foo {get;set;} 
    public double? Bar {get;set;} 
}
```

with endpoint like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Endpoint1([FromBody]AnObject anObject) 
{
    // if anObject is not valid (id is missing or incorrect types) ASP.net returns a BadRequest
    // if ok add anObject to DB with id as key
}
```

and then a second object like this that has the same fields but non nullable and Required with Range checking.

```
public class AMoreStringentObject 
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    [Required][Range(1,10)]
    public double Foo {get;set;} 
    [Required][Range(1,10)]
    public double Bar {get;set;} 
}
```

and endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Endpoint2(string id) 
{
    // get the AnObject from the DB with id matching parameter id
    // now want to validate this using the AMoreStringentObject
}
```

in the second end point I would like get the AnObject from the database and perform validation using the `DataAnnotations` library. The second object and the first are not the same (nullable type on first) so I can't simply automap them.  So i thought what I could do is serialize the AnObject to json and not write out things that are null, easy enough.  So I want to then call the validation that must occur somewhere in the asp.net magic that would throw out error messages like "Foo is required".  But how do I do that?  i.e. validate the json string using the AMoreStringentObject so that the Required attributes throw a BadRequest with the required error.  OR if there is a better way to go about this I'm all ears.

Additionally, I'm aware that I could do this with settings in the  json deserializer but you get an unhelpful exception when you do this.  I'd really like to get the BadRequest response that the Required field creates as this is a much more helpful message to the user.  eg the json exception has a json position which is no use to the user because it is the backend that has serialized it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [FluentValidation](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation) which can be [integrated](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html) into ASP.NET Core pipeline and will allow you to build reusable validations.

But if you want to use the build into the framework validation - you can look into [`Validator.TryValidateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?view=net-6.0) with manually created  [`ValidationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext?view=net-7.0):

```cs
AMoreStringentObject toValidate = ...;
var vc = new ValidationContext(toValidate, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(u, vc, results, true);
```

Comment: so i've explored that approach, the problem with that is I can't convert AnObject to AMoreStringentObject because of the nullable fields in AnObject i.e. when they're null what do I do?  If i deserialize it'll just default them to 0.  And so i have to then handle all that error checking myself and lose the benefits of the Required tags.  I want to perform the validation on the json which asp.net must do somewhere

Comment: i guess I could do something like set the values to double.MinValue when I deserialize which feels a bit hacky, but it feels like there is something missing here.  the other thing I could do is call another endpoint from within the code, which again I don't love the idea of!

Comment: @TimRutter just create a `AMoreStringentObject` and copy values to it? You can use Automapper for something like this if you don't want to do it manually.